# Understanding Dagger2 subcomponents

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have the following Dagger2 Architecture in my app:

```
-- AppComponent (@PerApplication)
  -- UserComponent (@PerUser)
    -- ActivityComponent (@PerActivity)
      -- ChatComponent (@PerActivity) <-- 1
```

Where:
AppComponent:

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, StorageModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    UserComponent plus(UserModule userComponent);

    //Exposed to sub-graphs.
    Context application();
}
```

UserComponent:

```
@PerUser
@Subcomponent(modules = {UserModule.class, RosterModule.class})
public interface UserComponent {
    ActivityComponent plus(ActivityModule activityModule);

    User getMe();

    UserRepository userRepository();
}
```

ActivityComponent:

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    ChatComponent plus(ChatModule chatComponent);

    //Exposed to sub-graphs.
    Context context();
}
```

ChatComponent:

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = {ChatModule.class})
public interface ChatComponent {
    void inject(ChatListFragment chatListFragment);
    void inject(ConversationFragment conversationFragment);
    void inject(NewConversationFragment newConversationFragment);
    void inject(CloudFilesFragment cloudFilesFragment);
    void inject(ChatActivity chatActivity);
    void inject(ConversationActivity conversationActivity);
    void inject(NewConversationActivity newConversationActivity);

    void inject(NewGroupActivity newGroupActivity);
    void inject(NewGroupFragment newGroupFragment);
}
```

I'm facing 2 problems:

First, how can I inject different `Context` to my classes ? Either App or Activity ??

And secondly, I'm facing a bizarre issue when trying to compile my code, the error is:

> Error:(23, 10) error:
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.domain.interactor.UseCase cannot be
>   provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.presentation.view.fragment.ChatListFragment.chatListPresenter
>   [injected field of type:
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.presentation.presenter.ChatListPresenter
>   chatListPresenter]
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.presentation.presenter.ChatListPresenter.(br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.domain.interactor.UseCase
>   chatDialogsUseCase,
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.domain.interactor.UseCase
>   adviceUserPresence, android.content.Context context) [parameter:
>   @javax.inject.Named("getChatDialogs")
>   br.com.animaeducacao.ulife.domain.interactor.UseCase
>   chatDialogsUseCase]

My ChatListFragment is:

```
@PerActivity
public class ChatListFragment extends BaseFragment implements ChatListView {

    @Inject
    ChatListPresenter chatListPresenter;
  ...
//called onActivityCreated()
private void initialize() {
        this.getComponent(ChatComponent.class).inject(this);
}
```

BaseFragment:

```
protected <C> C getComponent(Class<C> componentType) {
    return componentType.cast(((HasComponent<C>)getActivity()).getComponent());
  }
```

ChatListPresenter:

```
@PerActivity
public class ChatListPresenter implements Presenter {

    private final UseCase chatDialogsUseCase;
    private final UseCase adviceUserPresence;
    private final Context context;
    private ChatListView chatListView;

    @Inject
    public ChatListPresenter(@Named("getChatDialogs") UseCase chatDialogsUseCase,
                             @Named("adviceUserPresence") UseCase adviceUserPresence,
                             Context context) {
        this.chatDialogsUseCase = chatDialogsUseCase;
        this.adviceUserPresence = adviceUserPresence;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

The problem is, in my ChatModule class I have implemented all the `@Provides` necessary:

```
@Provides
    @PerActivity
    @Named("getChatDialogs")
    public UseCase provideChatDialogs(@Named("transactionalChatRepository") ChatRepository chatRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread) {
        return new GetUserChatDialogs(chatRepository, threadExecutor, postExecutionThread);
    }
```

Is this a good approach ? Why is this not compiling, what I am missing here ?
Sorry for the long post and thanks !

Comment: Please read some more tutorials about dagger. The error you get is probably because you provide only a named usecase. Also, you should not care about `context`. If you need the activity, inject the activity, if you need the context, you should probably go for the app context

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you have multiple problems.

1.) While you're using the subscoping correctly to a point (you **are** making `@Subcomponent`s properly at first), the `ChatComponent` doesn't actually subscope its parent component - basically, `ChatComponent` cannot be `@PerActivity`, it needs to be a fourth scope.

`@Subcomponent` annotation is just a way to create a subscoped component without having to specify it as a component dependency. It still needs its own "more specific" scope.

2.) to make subscoping work, you need to specify provision methods in your component for every dependency that that component is meant to provide, so that the subscoped components can inherit them.

For example, your `ApplicationComponent` doesn't have provision methods for what is in `StorageModule`, and therefore the dependencies provided by `StorageModule` cannot be inherited to subscoped components.

I however am not sure if you can just specify the class you're providing if it is not inside a module, and instead it is annotated with `@Inject` constructor and the class is marked with the scope.

Also, to allow in a scope hierarchy `A->B->C` for C to inherit from A, then B needs to have the provision methods of A as well.

So `UserComponent extends ApplicationComponent` is necessary, and `ActivityComponent extends UserComponent`, and `ChatComponent extends ActivityComponent`.

3.) You should use the `@Named("application")` and `@Named("activity")` annotations to specify two different `Context`, or instead just refer to them as `Application` and `Activity` in your module so that they don't get mixed up.

Comment: Quoting for Dagger2 Javadoc: "A subcomponent that inherits the bindings from a parent {@link Component} or
 * {@link Subcomponent}". I don't see why I should extend any interface using `@Subcomponent`. I tried, and I got a Stackoverflow error when building. Thanks for the answer and the explanations so far !

Comment: Well technically I know that component dependencies require it, I am not sure if subcomponents need it too as well. Did you change the scope of the chat component?

Comment: In that case, you will need to post your module code... But I think what would help is if you had classes for each usecase so you wouldn't have to use @Named on them, you might be forgetting one of them.